# Need to get ID tags of my page and display them for a Chrome Exstension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I could not find any question similar to mine, so I decided to ask, how do I fetch some pictures from my own website, they all have the id tag `post_p`.

I assume I have to use:

```
XMLHttpRequest
```

But do I fetch the content of my page via the client or via my website? I'm a little clueless here. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

to get an element by it's ID do this :

```
document.getElementById("id");
```

or as a function with :

```
var ge = function(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var element1 = ge("element1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions are run locally (ie client-side) so looking into server-side ways to get the id's is pretty pointless. If you want to get the id's of all images in the DOM, this can be quite easily done like so:

```
var allIds = [],
allImgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');//returns a array-like object, referencing all img elements

for (var i=0;i<allImgs.length;i++)
{
    allIds.push(allImgs[i].id);
}
```

If you needn't scan the entire DOM, you can select a particular (block) element in which to look:

```
var allImgs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('img');
//the rest is the same...
```

Just a personal note: Not sure if getting stuck in with AJAX calls and chrome extensions prior to getting to grips with JS basics is the best of ideas, though... but best of luck all the same